# How does Android MediaCodec create a decoder?

Tags: java, android, decoding, decoder

I've noticed that `java/android/media` has a method called `createDecoderByType()` that is supposed to return a `MediaCodec` object. However, when I look at the `MediaCodec.java` [source code on GoogleGit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/MediaCodec.java), I can't really see how the actual decoder is generated. Here is the code for that method:

```
    public static MediaCodec createDecoderByType(String type) {
    return new MediaCodec(type, true /* nameIsType */, false /* encoder */);
}
```

Then when I look at the constructor to see what is returned, this is what I see:

```
    private MediaCodec(
        String name, boolean nameIsType, boolean encoder) {
    native_setup(name, nameIsType, encoder);
}
```

Okay, great. Let's look at `native_setup()`. Here's the definition:

```
    private native final void native_setup(
        String name, boolean nameIsType, boolean encoder);
```

That function appears to have no body!

At first I assumed that this meant the method would be defined in a child class. But I am seeing this method called directly on `MediaCodec` itself in other functioning source code.

So my question is: Is there any way I can trace down and see how Android creates a decoder of a given type depending on the environment and parameters? I seem to have hit a dead end, and no amount of Googling is giving me any helpful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer to this the minute after I posted it...of course. The issue is with the `native` keyword. From [GeeksforGeeks:](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/native-keyword-java/)

> The native keyword is applied to a method to indicates that the method is implemented in native code using JNI (Java Native Interface).

This means that it can be written in another language such as C or C++, or invoke hardware stuff. The `MediaCodec` JNI code that I was looking for is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp).

Comment: Oftentimes this is C or C++ code. In this case, it appears to be C++: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thanks for the link. I actually found the source a couple minutes after posting this answer.